# assign to std:vector from a structure containing an array

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I am trying to assign data from a struct to a std::vector

Here is the code

```
struct myArray
{
   double * data;
   size_t   len;
};


typedef std::vector<double>  DoubleVect;


DoubleVect myvect;
MyArray myarr;

// code to initialize alloc and populate the MyArray variable
// ....


myvect.assign(&myarr.data, &myarr.data + myarr.len);  // compiler barfs here ...
```

Any idea why? and how may I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Get rid of the address operator and it will be fine. Taking the address of the data member `data` gives you an expression of type `double**`. This is certainly not what you want.

Comment: Doh! Sometimes all it needs is a second set of eyes (or a coffee break!)